# Sending an email in JavaScript on client side

Tags: javascript, html, email

Perhaps someone can tell me why this is happening and what I can do about it.  I'm trying to send an email from the client side.

Code follows (all client-side) ...

HTML:

```
    <button type="button" onclick="PrepEmail()">Contact Creator/Maintainer/Provider of This Data via email</button>
```

JS:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function PrepEmail() {
        var DBinfo, pnt, email, version, header;
        const ws = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:3000/');

        ws.onopen = function() {
            ws.send("DBInfo");
            ws.onmessage = function(e) {
                if (e.data == -1 || e.data == -2)
                    alert ('Email address for Creator of DataBase not available.');
                else {
                    DBinfo = e.data;
                    pnt = DBinfo.indexOf("DBCreatorEmail =");
                    if (pnt == -1)
                        alert ('Email address for Creator of DataBase not available.');
                    else {
                        email = getData(DBinfo, pnt);
                        if (email == "not specified")
                            alert ('Email address for Creator of DataBase not available.');
                        else {
                            header = "mailto:";
                            header += email + "?subject=";
                            pnt = DBinfo.indexOf("DBName =");
                            if (pnt == -1)
                                header += "DataBase";
                            else {
                                header += getData(DBinfo, pnt);
                                pnt = DBinfo.indexOf("DBVersion =");
                                if (pnt != -1) {
                                    version = getData(DBinfo, pnt);
                                    header += " (" + version + ")";
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        const terminationEvent = 'onpagehide' in self ? 'pagehide' : 'unload';
        window.addEventListener(terminationEvent, (event) => {
            if (event.persisted === false) {
                // client is gone
                ws.onclose = function () { };
                ws.close();
            }
        });

        SendEmail(header);
    }

    function SendEmail (header) {
        const windowRef = window.open(header, '_blank');

        windowRef.focus();
        setTimeout(function() {
            if(!windowRef.document.hasFocus()) {
                windowRef.close();
            }
        }, 500);
    }

    function getData (DB, p) {
        var pos1 = DB.indexOf('"', p) + 1;
        var pos2 = DB.indexOf('"', pos1);
        var data = DB.substring(pos1, pos2);
        if (data == "")
            return ("not specified")
        else
            return (data);
    }

    </script>
```

The WebSocket call works as expected, returning:

DBName = "The Real DB"
DBVersion = "20230101"
DBCreator = "Joe Blow"
DBCreatorEmail = "jb@foo.com"

Clicking the button gives a new tab with a completely blank page. The address line of the new tab contains "about:blank".

However, if I make the header variable a global and refrain from passing it - the first time I click the button I get the same thing: a new tab with a completely blank page and an address line containing "about:blank"; BUT if I click the button a second time it works fine and I get the following console messages in Inspect (the messages only appear after the second click):

Storage access automatically granted for origin “moz-nullprincipal:{c3a06e0d-3847-421d-b143-df87ff91029d}” on “http://999.999.9.999:8080”.
Uncaught DOMException: Permission denied to access property "document" on cross-origin object
SendEmail [http://999.999.9.999:8080/~devdir/Misc.html:65](http://999.999.9.999:8080/%7Edevdir/Misc.html:65)
setTimeout handler*SendEmail [http://999.999.9.999:8080/~devdir/Misc.html:64](http://999.999.9.999:8080/%7Edevdir/Misc.html:64)
PrepEmail [http://999.999.9.999:8080/~devdir/Misc.html:56](http://999.999.9.999:8080/%7Edevdir/Misc.html:56)
onclick [http://999.999.9.999:8080/~devdir/Misc.html:1](http://999.999.9.999:8080/%7Edevdir/Misc.html:1)

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm seeing correctly but you call `SendEmail(header)` outside of `onopen` instead of after completing the header

Comment: @Konrad, Son of a gun. I should have known that.  Thanks very much for your comment.  The routine works like it should now.